# VS Code - does not recognize php 8 syntax

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I have recently set up vsCode with PHP.
However, it shows errors on following lines.

```
public static function myFunction(): bool|string
```

> error : syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting ';' or '{'

```
$app->options('/{routes:.+}', fn (ResponseInterface $response) => $response);
```

> error : syntax error, unexpected '$response' (T_VARIABLE), expecting
> ')'

How can I make it recognize that this is the correct syntax.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Have you tried changing vscode's php location... https://stackoverflow.com/a/71316312/19070801

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to change the version of php in vscode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68639575/how-to-change-the-version-of-php-in-vscode)

Answer (score 2):

Unless you install a third-party extension that provides its own custom PHP parser, Visual Studio Code just relies in the PHP interpreter you install in order to lint files. That's provided by the **PHP Language Features** builtin extension.

I will pick your PHP interpreter from your `PATH` variable. A simple way to figure it out is to type `php -v` in a CMD or PowerShell window:

```
C:\>php -v
PHP 8.1.15 (cli) (built: Jan 31 2023 23:50:48) (ZTS Visual C++ 2019 x64)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.15, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.1.15, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

If you didn't add it, or you want to use a different interpreter, you can set a custom path in the `php.validate.executablePath` directive.

At the time of writing there isn't a visual editor for this setting so you'll need to edit it as JSON. Windows directory separator (`\`) is a special character in JSON, so you need to either escape it or use Unix separator (`/`)

```
"php.validate.executablePath": "C:\\PHP\\php.exe"
"php.validate.executablePath": "C:/PHP/php.exe"
```

Answer (score -1):

Open Visual Studio Code settings and verify the `intelephense.environment.phpVersion` directive is set to `"8.1.0"`.