# Why error? [Syntax error: unexpected token '?' PHP(PHP2014)]

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code, syntax-error, laravel-9

I'm practicing coding using Laravel 9 (for the first time) and reinstalling it. However, running it through cmd or Terminal throws an error saying the following.

> Syntax error: unexpected token '?' PHP(PHP2014) in the folder
> vender/symfony/http-kernel/Attribule/MapDataTime.php.

[image: error 1]

> Syntax error: unexpected token 'Requirement' PHP(PHP2014)] The other
> will be in  vender/symfony/routing/Requirement/Requirement.php

[image: error 2]

I'm looking for a solution.

Comment: what is the version of your PHP ?

Comment: To copy text from your editor, you can highlight it with the mouse and hit Ctrl+C. You can then paste it into your Stack Overflow question with Ctrl+V and format it as source code with the `{}` (Code Sample) toolbar button.

Answer (score 2):

You're using PHP 8.0 (according to the PHP version in your IDE screenshot).

ENUMs were [introduced in PHP 8.1](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.enumerations.php).

See here if you need help changing the PHP version (I'm assuming you're using Visual Studio Code, based on your screenshots) - [how to change the version of php in vscode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68639575/how-to-change-the-version-of-php-in-vscode)