# syntax PHP recognized in my vscode editor

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code, laravel-blade

`@extends('layouts.vertical', ['title' => 'Payroll'])` 
on my blade page
i am getting
this error message
`Syntax error: unexpected token ','PHP(PHP2014)`

in my vscode

`@extends('layouts.vertical', ['title' => 'Payroll'])`

to have no error

Comment: There are extensions in VSCode to handle `.blade.php` files, since they use their own unique syntax (`@{whatever}` directives, `{{ ... }}`, `{!! ... !!}`, etc.). Browse through the available plugins and see if any of them fix your issue.

Comment: a question similar to your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74580227/why-error-syntax-error-unexpected-token-phpphp2014