# Problems with php versions on xampp and vs code

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xampp, composer-php, homebrew

On my new `Mac Air M2`, I downloaded `VSCode` and then I downloaded `XAMPP 7.4.3` in `/Applications` folder, because I wanted to use `PHP 7.4.3`.

Next, I downloaded `Homebrew` and installed `PHP`. It installed `PHP 8.2.5`.

So now the problem is my `XAMPP` is using `PHP 7.4.3` and `VSCode` is using `PHP 8.2.5`.

I also downloaded `composer` from `brew`. My `composer.json` file requires minimum `PHP 8.1`.

However, I want to work in `PHP 7.4.3`.

When I run `php -v` in `VSCode` I get `PHP 8.2.5`, and when I save a file with `php_info();` in `htdocs` and open with a browser, I get `PHP 7.4.3`.

So it is clear that `XAMPP` is using `PHP 7.4.3` and `VSCode` is using `PHP 8.2.5`.

What should I do to make `VSCode` use `PHP 7.4.3`?

Comment: So why did you download/install PHP 8.2? XAMPP comes with a version of PHP as part of it

Comment: If your composer.json requires a PHP version you don't want to use, why not change what you've written to your composer.json? But please keep in mind that PHP 7.4 is nearing its end of life, and PHP 7.4.3 itself is even older than the latest PHP 7.4 release

Answer (score 2):

This is for a windows env, but I assume it will be similiar.

I have a launch.json file for each project as below, where I can select one of many versions of PHP that I have installed.

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [        
        {
            "name": "Debug currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9003,
            //"runtimeExecutable":"C:\\wamp64\\bin\\php\\php5.6.40\\php.exe",
            //"runtimeExecutable":"C:\\wamp64\\bin\\php\\php7.0.33\\php.exe",
            //"runtimeExecutable":"C:\\wamp64\\bin\\php\\php7.1.33\\php.exe",
            //"runtimeExecutable":"C:\\wamp64\\bin\\php\\php7.2.34\\php.exe",
            //"runtimeExecutable":"C:\\wamp64\\bin\\php\\php7.3.32\\php.exe",
            //"runtimeExecutable":"C:\\wamp64\\bin\\php\\php7.4.32\\php.exe",
            //"runtimeExecutable":"C:\\wamp64\\bin\\php\\php8.0.25\\php.exe", 
            //"runtimeExecutable":"C:\\wamp64\\bin\\php\\php8.1.14\\php.exe" 
            "runtimeExecutable":"C:\\wamp64\\bin\\php\\php8.2.4\\php.exe" 
        }
    ]
}
```

If you do something similiar in yours you can get VSCode to launch with any verions of PHP you have on your system