# How to set the PHP version on my VSCode? I am currently using version 7.4, but the code prompt has always been the latest version 8.0

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

How to set the PHP version on my VSCode? I am currently using version 7.4, but the code prompt has always been the latest version 8.0

[image]

[image]

My code prompts for PHP version 8.0 each time, but I need version 7.4. What do I need to do to use the previous version?

Comment: Built-in PHP support works our of the box. What third-party extension are you using?

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68639575/how-to-change-the-version-of-php-in-vscode/#answer-71316312)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.