# How can I do a good syntax for this situation i have an error syntax

Tags: php, html, function, parameter-passing

```
function  get_information($country = "Default argument", $name = "Default argument", $age = "Default argument", $address = "Default argument") {
    $line_one = "you country is $country your name is $name <br>";
    $line_two = "your age is $age your adress is $address";
    return $line_one . $line_two;
 }
echo get_information(address: "Rabat Capitale");
```

i wanna a solution for this syntax i have a problem on parameter passing by default value

Comment: What version of PHP are yo using? That syntax was added in 8.0, you can't use it with older versions.

Comment: I use The latest Version so what's the prob here !

Comment: In that case it should work. What problem are you having?

Comment: the code is working  but the visual studio  code tell me that i have an error on syntax !

Comment: on The line that i make a call to function  !! echo get_information(address: "Rabat Capitale");

Comment: That's a vscode configuration problem, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68278342/vs-code-does-not-recognize-php-8-syntax

Comment: yeah i see but it still the same prob can you !

Comment: Can I what? I don't use vscode.

Comment: vscode must be using an older version of PHP. Make sure you point it to the PHP 8 executable.

Comment: I just updated it and got into the settings I have the latest version of php !

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. You must not have done it correctly. Go back to the other question and try again.